# Как можно сделать такой фон для сайта?

Tags: css

Как можно сделать такой фон для сайта?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rSl5EP8Bcw

Comment: @eprivalov1, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Если градиент имеет только две начальных точки, то с помощью css:

```
linear-gradient
```

Если больше, то лучше картинкой. Либо с помощью canvas. Нашел вот: http://toster.ru/q/38905

Comment: Вообще-то у градиента нет ограничения на число точек. К тому же, больше похоже на radial, чем на linear. И мигание...

Comment: @Qwertiy предложите свой вариант. "Мигание" - это вы об изменении фона? Я про ограничение количества точек ничего не говорил, прочитайте внимательней. Радиальным градиентом такое получится, но linear тоже https://jsfiddle.net/gp4d37Lt/1/

Comment: _"Если градиент имеет только две начальных точки"_ - а это про что?
Мигание - это про то, что на видео фон постоянно меняется. Не знаю, получится ли это с помощью анимации css'ного градиетна сделать, или нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну так где я про ограничение написал?

Comment: _"Если больше, то лучше картинкой."_ - почему тогда?

Comment: @Qwertiy а почему бы и нет?

Comment: [Ясно](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2171/178988)